# Getting header information inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, http-headers

Is there a way to get the HTTP header information of the current page in JavaScript?
I am trying to get the header information of a page like `referer` and other headers. How can I get those values in a JavaScript function so that I can send that information to a Java applet? The problem while I am making an Ajax call and getting header information is the referer will change to current page than the original referer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing HTTP Headers in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: is there a specific data you need or you just need all? Some data is available in multiple JavaScript objects, like referer is document.referrer

Comment: Don't forget to accept someone's answer (click the check mark next to the answer), or at least give them a vote up (click the gray up arrow), for spending time to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use document.referrer for referrer. Use Ajax to get the rest.

```
function getHeadersAjax(url) {
   var r = GetXmlHttpObject();
   r.open('HEAD', url, false);
   r.send(null);
   return {
      status: r.status, 
      statusText: r.statusText, 
      referrer: document.referrer,
      rawheaders: r.getAllResponseHeaders()
   };
}
```

Comment: I already loaded a page and i want to get the information of that page. in this case will it rewrite the information  ? i mean to say the referrer to that page and other details ?

Comment: You have to be specific about what headers you want, but I can tell you that some headers are only available by using ajax to fetch the same page a 2nd time. In my example, use `url = document.location.href`. Please keep in mind that I am talking about headers sent by the server. If you want headers sent by the browser, you must use a server page that will reflect that info back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use \

```
document.location.href
```

It will return the header response