# How to know mime-type or content-type of current loaded page via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mime-types, content-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing HTTP Headers in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript)

I want know a mime-type or content-type of current loaded page via JavaScript.
the thing I wanna do is to check whether it is rss or html of the page.

The only thing I could find is 'document.contentType', but it is supported in Gecko ( firefox ).

does anyone know how to do it via JavaScript ?

Comment: FWIW, currently `document.contentType` does seem to be supported by Chrome, Firefox and Edge, on Windows at least.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `XHR` request.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', document.location, false);
xhr.send(null);

alert(xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type"));​ // content-type
```

1. Initialise the request
2. Send the request
3. Get the desired header using `ref.getResponseHeader()`

Also check out the links below.

- [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript)
- [Getting header information inside JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357941/getting-header-information-inside-javascript)
- http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getresponseheader-method